# Blue Prism - Save and Read Pdf

Tags: pdf, save, save-as, blueprism

I am trying to save a pdf which opens via Web link and after saving want to read all texts present in the PDF file.

I have tried to save it by sending "send keys" (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) as used in BP but was not able to save it.

Also, for reading the data present in PDF(any other pdf) tried with sending key strokes <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> but was not successful.

Comment: Hard to say without more information about how you tried to do it. It sounds, however, like you are not sending the send keys properly/the pdf reader is not acknowledging the send keys.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, (if you haven't done this already) you could create an object + model that attaches to the open (running).pdf instance, then with the spied element of save button/option in your .pdf, proceed from there with further elements/clicks to save it wherever you want. This should be a few clicks using Navigate stages. Same principle if you are using sendkeys; you still need to use the root element on the model that attaches/launches the .pdf. If you haven't done this, the sendkeys are just never going to work.  As to capturing the contents, I am not aware of any downloadable VBOs that will do this, I know there are some from MS Word to capture stuff in tables, etc... into a Collection stage, but not for .pdf. You can try the sendkeys again once you are sure you are using the root element of the correct model, or you might have a go at creating your own solution using a code stage.

Comment: I will check this and let you know the results.